# Using python assign each record to respective column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have data frame with some records. I need to combine required records and assign to new variable and put it into the same dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp_c': [17.0, 25.0]},
              index=['Portland', 'Berkeley'])
df = df.assign(temp_f=df['temp_c'] * 9 / 5 + 32)
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
         temp_c           temp_f             new_type
portland  17.0             62.6       [{'temp_c': '17.0', 'temp_f': '62.6'}]
Berkley   25.0             77.0       [{'temp_c': '25.0', 'temp_f': '77.0'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='records'`:

```
df['new_type'] = df[['temp_c','temp_f']].to_dict(orient='records')
print (df)
          temp_c  temp_f                          new_type
Portland    17.0    62.6  {'temp_c': 17.0, 'temp_f': 62.6}
Berkeley    25.0    77.0  {'temp_c': 25.0, 'temp_f': 77.0}
```

If need nested lists use:

```
df['new_type'] = [[x] for x in df[['temp_c','temp_f']].to_dict(orient='records')]
print (df)
          temp_c  temp_f                            new_type
Portland    17.0    62.6  [{'temp_c': 17.0, 'temp_f': 62.6}]
Berkeley    25.0    77.0  [{'temp_c': 25.0, 'temp_f': 77.0}]
```